# Better percentile rank for subsets of data that works like PERCENTRANK.INC() in Excel?

Tags: excel, algorithm, excel-formula, formula

We use PERCENTILERANK.INC() in Excel with no issues. The column below labeled "Pctl Inc" uses this formula:

```
=PERCENTRANK.INC($B$2:$B$6,B2,3)
```

I also built a formula that ranks a subset of values among the subset data based on another columns text values. My formula works just like the one in this link:
http://www.exceltactics.com/calculate-percentile-conditional-ranking-using-sumproduct/

Here is the specific formula I am referring to in that link:

```
=(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$6=A2)*(B2>=$B$2:$B$6)))/COUNTIF($A$2:$A$6,A2)
```

(Note that the site link has a typo in the formula and mine is the one you want to use to test.)

The formula above is labeled "Pctl W/in" in the data I provide below.

The column "Subset Labels" indicates the subset they should be in. More on that later. "Values to Rk" are the items being ranked in all cases.

My goal is to change only the "Pctl W/in" formula so that it returns the same values as the "Pctl Inc" column would if subsetting weren't involved. I.e. we like the behavior of the "Pctl Inc" column, but we need a formula to mimic that ranking style for a subset of the same data.

Here is the data you can use to create a "match". Note that I intentionally have all of the "Subset Labels" the same so you can match the ranks easily. The Pctl Inc and Pctl W/in value should be the same here since they all have the same Subset Labels:

**Without Subsets:**

- Subset Labels,   Values to Rk,   Pctl Inc,   Pctl W/in
- a,   100,    1,  1
- a,   0,  0.25,   0.4
- a,   6,  0.5,    0.6
- a,   -1, 0,  0.2
- a,   7,  0.75,   0.8

The "Pctl W/in" data is wrong, hence this post.The values above are what I am getting currently and I would like them to be like the "Pctl Inc" values when you take out the subset component:

**With Subsets:**

For the a's:

- Subset Labels    Values to Rk    Pctl Inc
- a,   100,    1
- a,   0,  0.5
- a,   -1, 0

For the b's:

- Subset Labels,   Values to Rk,   Pctl Inc
- b,   6,  0
- b,   7,  1

In other words, the ranks for all should look like this if it is working correctly:

- Subset Labels,   Values to Rk,   Pctl Inc,   Pctl W/in
- a,   100,    1,  1
- a,   0,  0.25,   0.5
- b,   6,  0.5,    0
- a,   -1, 0,  0
- b,   7,  0.75,   1

PS - can someone tell me how one creates good grids in stackoverflow posts?

Comment: nice tables are created with this site: http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
=IFERROR(1-(COUNTIFS(A$2:A$6,A2,B$2:B$6,">="&B2)-1)/(COUNTIF(A$2:A$6,A2)-1),1)
```

Notes:

1. An array formula could solve this more simply, but I cannot use an array formula.
2. The IFERROR(...,1) wrap solves a #DIV/0 error when there is only one of any particular Subset Label (ex. many a's and only one b).
3. This correctly mimics PERCENTRANK.INC() when there is a tie in ranked values.